# Absolute Value Rules

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Why can $\lvert \cfrac{3}{x} - 3 \rvert$ be turned into $\cfrac{3}{\lvert x \rvert} \lvert x-1 \rvert$? Where can I find more rules/tricks like this?

Comment: $\frac 3x-3=\frac 3x-\frac{3x}{x}=\frac 3x\left(1-x\right)$

Comment: The 1-x can be flipped around to x-1 because of absolute value right?

Comment: Yes. It is $|1-x|=|x-1|.$

Comment: It is always true that $|a b -a| = |a(b-1)| = |a||b-1|=|a||1-b|$. This is because $|xy|=|x||y|$ and $|x|=|-x|$.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor and take the absolute value of the factor out.

That is $$ |xy|=|x||y|$$

You can also switch the signs inside absolute value that is

$$|x-y|=|y-x|$$